# Container Optimized System performance

Tags: containers, google-compute-engine

I am doing some load tests and according to my observations seems the cos-stable machine underperforms a normal linux machine.

I have started up the cos-stable machine with a container running node-alpine linux with a js application and execute a load test, then I did the same using an ubuntu machine, installing the node on it to run the same js application.

Both OS' were using the same resources, n1 machines with 2vcpu, 8Gram and 10G SSD disk.

Does anyone have information about how to tune the cos-stable container to have the same performance as I had in the ubuntu machine?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) What needs to be tuned? 2) AFAIK, you cannot **tune** Container Optimized OS internal settings. If you need to customize the container environment, you will need to build your own VM, install Docker, make desired changes, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was expecting the cos-stable should have almost the same performance as pure OS Linux by default instead of the necessity to do additional configurations.

Comment: In order to determine what needs to be optimized, you need data on what is the issue. What analysis and/or benchmarking have you performed? Edit your question with those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well according to the comment of [this user](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-node-versus-ubuntu/37131/4) in the docker forum

> I have to agree with the others, I always use official images if I can and I always select the Alpine version if available. Why use Alpine? Two reasons:
>
> Much small images. Ubuntu is 188MB alone. Then you add your app on top
> of that probably exceeding 200MB. Alpine Linux is only 4MB! After
> adding my Python runtime and code most of my images are only 52MB.
> Compare that will almost 200MB of Ubuntu. Smaller images are smaller
> upload/download and take up less disk space.

In adding to that, if you are running the same application in both machines with different OS you have to consider pros and cons of using that OS

if you want to customize your Container Optimized OS VM creation you can follow the instructions [in this link](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#advanced)

I hope this information can be useful.